# Spring Cloud Dataflow kafka-source-kafka throwing error

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a steam application using SCDF kafka-source-kafka as a kafka supplier config. Below are the properties to configure the external source kafka as a consumer config.

```
app.kafka-source-kafka.kafka.supplier.topics=TEST_TOPIC
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=xxxxxxxx
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=B2B_EH_PASTHROUGH_FALLBACK
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"xxxxxx\" password=\"xxxxxx\";
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/secrets/kafka.client.truststore.jks
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.ssl.truststore.password=xxxx
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.consumer.properties.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.listener.async-acks=true


Logs:
2024-01-04T05:45:27.711Z  INFO 1 --- [main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [xxxxx:9090]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = consumer-B2B_EH_PASTHROUGH_FALLBACK-1
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = B2B_EH_PASTHROUGH_FALLBACK

After few minuits----------->

"clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig" values got changed and trying to connect internal kafka brokers.
2024-01-04T05:46:45.754Z  INFO 1 --- [binder-health-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [10.100.172.208:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
```

Error:
Connection to node -1 (my-release-kafka.springdata.svc.cluster.local/10.100.172.208:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed

Not sure why consumer/supplier bootstrap servers values got changed post successfully joined the external source kafka group.

Successfully logged in.
2024-01-04T05:45:28.226Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.1
2024-01-04T05:45:28.226Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8a516edc2755df89
2024-01-04T05:45:28.226Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1704347128225
2024-01-04T05:45:28.318Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-B2B_EH_PASTHROUGH_FALLBACK-1, groupId=B2B_EH_PASTHROUGH_FALLBACK] Subscribed to topic(s): EIS.TOPIC.PASS.EH.IN.DIT
2024-01-04T05:45:28.409Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started bean 'kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec'; defined in: 'class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/fn/supplier/kafka/KafkaSupplierConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.cloud.fn.supplier.kafka.KafkaSupplierConfiguration.kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec(org.springframework.cloud.fn.supplier.kafka.KafkaSupplierProperties,org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory,org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider,org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider,org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider,org.springframework.cloud.fn.common.config.ComponentCustomizer)'
2024-01-04T05:45:28.521Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-01-04T05:45:28.715Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .c.s.a.k.s.k.KafkaSourceKafkaApplication : Started KafkaSourceKafkaApplication in 31.902 seconds (process running for 34.939)

Comment: Try with this instead: `app.kafka-source-kafka.spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=xxxxxxxx`

Comment: Same issue, consumer config bootstrap values got changed automatically after 2min      Logs:  2024-01-04T05:46:45.754Z  INFO 1 --- [binder-health-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
 allow.auto.create.topics = true
 auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
 auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
 auto.offset.reset = latest
 bootstrap.servers = [10.100.172.208:9092]
 check.crcs = true
 client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `binder-health` means the thread for `KafkaBinderHealthIndicator`. We see those `o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig` every time when `consumerFactory.createConsumer()` is called. And there is indeed one for the metadata call in the `KafkaBinderHealthIndicator`.

so, it is not changed, rather a new `KafkaConsumer` instance.

It is created by the `kafkaBinderHealthIndicator` bean definition:

```
    if (!props.containsKey(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG)) {
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                configurationProperties.getKafkaConnectionString());
    }
    ConsumerFactory<?, ?> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    KafkaBinderHealthIndicator indicator = new KafkaBinderHealthIndicator(
            kafkaMessageChannelBinder, consumerFactory);
```

I'm not sure why that brokers config for health indicator is different after all of that logic, but if you have some simple Spring Cloud Stream application to reproduce, feel free to raise a GH issue for Spring Cloud Stream for further investigation on our side.

Nothing to do with Spring Cloud Dataflow though.

Comment: Thanks for your deep analysis. I resolved the issue by disabling the kafka binder health checks. "app.kafka-source-kafka.management.health.binders.enabled=false" Now the consumer working perfectly.